# Multiple commands using a .command script at launch

Tags: macos, script, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to figure out why this command script isn't working.

> killall Google\ Chrome;
>
> open /Application/Google\ Chrome.app -args --disable-restore-session-state

. I am trying to kill any instance of Chrome that happens to open on startup. Then launch Chrome with an argument. I have to run the script twice to get Chrome to launch. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I also had to run `killall Google\ Chrome; open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-restore-session-state` twice if Chrome was already open. Either of these worked the first time though:

`osascript -e 'quit app "Google Chrome"' 2> /dev/null && sleep 0.5; open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-restore-session-state`

`killall Google\ Chrome 2> /dev/null && sleep 0.5; open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-restore-session-state`

`killall` sends the process a `TERM` signal, which should generally be safe, but sending Chrome a quit Apple event allows it to for example ask for confirmation if there is unsubmitted text in a form.

`open -a` is usually just as fast as specifying the full path to the application bundle.